# Generate jpg thumbnails from pdf file and display on web page

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to generate jpg thumbnails from a pdf file to display on a website.  I have two issues:

1. the code i used below prints out the following error message:

"Uncaught ImagickException: Postscript delegate failed `1Mpublic.pdf': No such file or directory"

2. I am unsure that I have used the correct HTML syntax to display the generated jpg thumbnails images that I get from the code below.  As I get a bunch of garbled symbols displayed.

   ```
   $im = new imagick('1Mpublic.pdf');

   // Calculate number of thumbnails in document
   $numPagesPdfDoc = $im -> getNumberImages();


    $allThumbNails = '';

    for($i=0; $i<=$numPagesPdfDoc; $i++){

        $pdfPage = '1Mpublic.pdf['.$i.']';
        $im = new imagick($pdfPage);
        $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
        $im->setResolution( 300, 300 );

        $aThumbNail = '<div class="cl_1">'.$im.'<div><br>';
        $allThumbNails .= $aThumbNail;

   }

   echo $allThumbNails;
   ```

Comment: The next problem you'll encounter is this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49711489/522479

Comment: ImageMagick is a **raster** image processor - it works on a raster, or grid of pixels - not vectors. Anything that is not on  a raster is rasterised before **ImageMagick** gets to work processing pixels. Set the resolution **before** reading the file. If you set it after ImageMagick has rasterised the PDF onto a 2-D raster grid, it is too late - the details will be gone because the grid was too coarse - it is initially 72 dpi.